# 'Configurable product' is losing currency format after choosing an option on dropdown menu

Tags: configurable-product, price, ce-1.8.1.0, currency, dropdown-attribute

everyone.

The product's price is shown correctly, format and currency symbol. But when I choose an option from the dropdown, the price loses format and the symbol disappears. Does anyone here has seen this issue? How to fix it?

Example: http://coletivix.com/t-shirt.html

Answer (score 2):

I found what was causing the problem.
The field (System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup

> Custom Currency Format) was filled and probably it resulted in a conflict some how.
>   Letting it empty solved my problem.